# Webscraping with requests returning parent webpage HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from a specific website using the **requests** and **Beautiful Soup** libraries. Unfortunately, I am not receiving the HTML for that page, but for the parent page **https://salesweb.civilview.com**. Thank you for your help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example="https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=473016965"
exampleGet=requests.get(example)
exampleGetText=exampleGet.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(exampleGetText,"lxml")
soup
```

Comment: So you are receiving HTML from https://salesweb.civilview.com and not https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=473016965

Comment: Exactly. Interesting that when I click the hyperlink for the detailed URL on my phone, I am redirected to the parent page. Could this be connected?

Comment: yeah give me sec :) (PS: is the `example` URL just something random, because when I visit it appears to be empty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed a cookie to the request:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookie = {'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'rk2b0dxast1eyu5jvxezltgh'}

example="https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=473016964"
exampleGet=requests.get(example, cookies=cookie)
exampleGetText=exampleGet.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(exampleGetText,"lxml")
soup.title

<title>Sales Listing Detail</title>
```

That particular cookie may not work for you, so you'll need manually navigate to that page one time, then go into the developer (web inspector) tools in your browser, and lookup the cookie under "Headers" in the network tab. My cookie looked like 'ASP.NET_SessionId=rk2b0dxast1eyu5jvxezltgh'.

The cookie should be valid for other property pages as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have never had to do this before so I will need to read up on this. Thank you very much! Is there a general rule on which website require you to feed cookies to scrape them?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Someone with better knowledge of networks or web development might offer more insight. But in my experience, I've never noticed a predictable pattern. Some require them, some don't.

Comment: Well, this will work until the cookie expires which usually takes a couple of hours.

Comment: True. So if you want to avoid having to manually deal with headers, cookies, and such there are other options such as selenium.  It's a little more work, but maybe worth it.

Comment: If you use a session requests will handle the cookie for you, eg session=requests.Session() . Then visit the parent page first like this r = session.get(url). That'll give you the cookie in the session instance so when you call the intended url it should work - r = session.get(url2).